# Unlock phone to toggle wifi?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a galaxy s6 with Verizon on marshmallow, and every time I try to toggle wifi from the lock screen I am forced to unlock the phone. This isn't really a hassle, more of a minor inconvenience, but it doesn't make sense that Samsung would design the lock screen like that. I know the iPhone has excellent security, and it doesn't require the phone to be unlocked to toggle wifi, so this isn't a security measure. This also happened in lollipop. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: What Android version is that? On my tablet mit Android 5.1 I can swipe the lockscreen from the very top and get a menu to toggle various values, including wifi, bluetooth, orientation, brightness.

Comment: Actually, I would think that having to unlock the phone to change any setting especially disable connectivity is a security issue. What if your phone was connected to WiFi as a security camera? Someone could disable the WiFi and there goes your camera.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the way Samsung chose to implement it... The quick toggle panel on most stock Android or near-stock devices is accessible without unlocking the device, although anything other than a toggle, such as selecting a different WiFi network, requires unlocking.

You would need to flash a custom ROM in order to get the desired result due to Samsung's customizations being so non-standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
Go to Settings>Lock Screen and Security>Secure lock settings and
Disable Lock network and security
Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Secure lock settings is the way as earlier mentioned.
I would rather everything except Torch is locked.  Sound can be turned off/on when phone is locked, and on some phones bluetooth as well.

Another thing I would like is (if phone went missing) to locate the phone WITHOUT the Notification "Device Located" popping up.  I rather who has it, doesn't know I'm on too them.

Answer (score -2):

Download [Next Lock Screen](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next) app and you can do that stuff without unlocking